# Using array_get in Laravel with dynamic keys

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a calculation like this in my code

```
foreach ($result as $point) {
  @$pointTotals[$point->date][$point->app_id] += $point->revenue;
 }
```

So I would like to avoid the `@` symbol here and would like to use `array_get` instead. But will this support dynamic indexes and can I ue it like this ?

```
foreach ($result as $point) {
    $existingPoint = array_get($pointTotals, $point->date.$point->app_id, 0);
    $pointTotals[$point->date][$point->app_id] = $existingPoint + $point->revenue;
}
```

I am not getting any error here and so I think this is working fine. The thing here I can't test this I don't have any data and all are zeros. So I would like to confirm this will work fine with dynamic keys.

Comment: looking at the docs, i expect you need `array_get($pointTotals, $point->date . '.' . $point->app_id, 0)`